# Magento 1.9 on PHP 7.2 - phpseclib failed to open stream

Tags: magento

I have installed the latest Magento version 1.9.4.5 on PHP 7.2.33. At the file /var/log/system.log, I frequently see the below lines:

```
DEBUG (7): include(Phpseclib\Crypt\Base.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory /lib/Varien/Autoload.php
DEBUG (7): include(Phpseclib\Crypt\Base.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory /lib/Varien/Autoload.php
DEBUG (7): include(): Failed opening 'Phpseclib\Crypt\Base.php' for inclusion (include_path='/app/code/local:/app/code/community:/app/code/core:/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear')/lib/Varien/Autoload.php

DEBUG (7): include(Phpseclib\Crypt\Blowfish.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory /lib/Varien/Autoload.php
DEBUG (7): include(Phpseclib\Crypt\Blowfish.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory /lib/Varien/Autoload.php
DEBUG (7): include(): Failed opening 'Phpseclib\Crypt\Blowfish.php' for inclusion (include_path='/app/code/local:/app/code/community:/app/code/core:/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear')/lib/Varien/Autoload.php

DEBUG (7): include(Phpseclib\Crypt\Random.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory /lib/Varien/Autoload.php
DEBUG (7): include(Phpseclib\Crypt\Random.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory /lib/Varien/Autoload.php
DEBUG (7): include(): Failed opening 'Phpseclib\Crypt\Random.php' for inclusion (include_path='/app/code/local:/app/code/community:/app/code/core:/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear')/lib/Varien/Autoload.php
```

I have checked the below files under the Magento root directory and they are all exist:

```
/lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Base.php
/lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Blowfish.php
/lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Random.php
```

Is this problem related with PHP 7.2?

Comment: Did you check compatibility requirements for the Magent1.9 ??

Comment: Try to downgrade your PHP version to PHP5. to test it.

Comment: There's no point to downgrade to PHP 5.x even if it works, as these versions of PHP are no longer supported.

Comment: I have given an option to test what exactly issue you are facing ??